# repeat command for every argument in variable

Tags: bash, shell, backup

```
#!/bin/sh
dblist=mail ftp www
for arg in $dblist; do
mysqldump -u dumper --password=$dbpass --socket $socket --database $dblist >> /tmp/backup/$dblist.sql
done
```

Every database from variable dblist should write a new mysqldump line and add the database names into the according fields, how can this be achieved?

Comment: All you're missing above is to quote the multi-word value: `dblist="mail ftp www"` -- the unquoted `$dblist` will allow the for loop will iterate over the 3 words. Also, fix the errors in using `$dblist` instead of `$arg` in the mysqldump command

Answer (score 2):

Use variable `arg` (i.e. your database name) to create a separate sql dump file for each database like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
declare -a dblist=(mail ftp www)
for arg in "${dblist[@]}"
do
   mysqldump -u dumper --password=$dbpass --socket $socket --database $arg >> /tmp/backup/$arg.sql
done
```

Comment: The preferred way to expand an array variable is `"${dblist[@]}"` (don't forget the double-quotes!) -- this preserves spaces in array elements, avoids glob expansion, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Why not declare `dblist` as an array ?

```
dblist=(mail ftp www)
for arg in ${dblist}; do
   mysqldump .... $arg
```

and use the `$arg` variable in your invocation.

Here's a [bash array tutorial](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-array-tutorial/).

Answer (score 0):

```
dblist=(mail ftp)

for arg in ${dblist[*]}
do
   mysqldump -u $dbuser --password=$dbpass --socket $socket --database $arg >> /tmp/backup/$arg.sql
done
```

works, thank you!